# How can I capture the name of the Icon element that's the child of IconButton in Material UI for reference in IconButton's onClick?

Tags: material-ui, iconbutton

I have this `IconButton` which contains `AddCircleIcon`:

```
          <IconButton
            color="primary"
            aria-label="add foo to bar"
            name={ bar.name }
            onClick={ (e) => {
              console.log(e.target.name)
              console.log(e.target)
            }}
          >
            <AddCircleIcon
              name={ bar.name }
            />
          </IconButton>
```

There's a distinction between clicking on the icon and clicking on the button. Hovering over the icon shows a dim outline around it, the edge of which is the button:

[image]

Clicking on the centre of these two, on the plus sign, `undefined` is printed on the console. Clicking on the button area outside the icon shows the `bar.name`, which is coming from the button.

How would I be able to reference `e.target.name` when clicking anywhere on the button, including the icon?

My understanding so far about what's happening is that the `onClick` function is run when the icon is clicked upon as well since the icon is contained within the button, however, the event target is the icon. If that's the case, I don't understand why `undefined` is printed, as the icon also has `name` set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `console.log` prints `<path d=...` for the icon, does not have a name, no children, appears to be an svg wrapper with `nearestViewportElement: <svg ...` along with `farthestViewportElement: <svg ...`, `parentNode`, `parentElement`, `ownerSVGElement`, - the both of which have the `name`!

Upon looking up how to access the parent for an event on an element, I discovered `event.currentTarget`. Using this, I was able to avoid a conditional check on `e.target.name` as `e.currentTarget.name` prints the name correctly when clicking anywhere on the button, without having to set the name on `IconButton`.

[Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):
The `currentTarget` read-only property of the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. **It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.**

Answer (score 0):

If we need value and name from IconButton then we have to use `event.currentTarget.name`

```
<IconButton
    size='small'
    name='Name'
    value={rowIndex}
    onClick={rowCallback}
>
    <FileCopyIcon />
</IconButton>
```

**Error:**

```
const rowCallback = useCallback(event => {

    const name = event.target.name
    const value = event.target.value
    
    console.log(name, value)

}, [  ])
```

**Solution:**

```
const rowCallback = useCallback(event => {

    const name = event.currentTarget.name
    const value = event.currentTarget.value
    
    console.log(name, value)

}, [  ])
```